# C#: compiling and runtimeconfig

Tags: .net

Why won't the built code run?

In the `cwproj` I have

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It builds and runs fine in VisualStudio but not when deployed using the results of an Azure pipeline.

This seems to reproduce the problem locally, using the command that I think the Azure pipeline is running.

```
> dotnet restore src\SomeCode.sln
...
> dotnet build src\SomeCode.sln --configuration Release --no-restore
...
> dotnet publish src\SomeCode.csproj --configuration Release --framework net5.0 --runtime win-x64 --no-build --no-self-contained --output BuildTest
...
> BuildTest\SomeCode.exe
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\Work\SomeCode\BuildTest\PSomeCode.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in 'C:\Work\SomeCodeBuildTest\SomeCode.runtimeconfig.json'.
```

```
> dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.203
 Commit:    383637d63f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.6
  Commit:  478b2f8c0e

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.816 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.409 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Here is the `runtimeconfig.json`

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.6"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.6"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

I don't even understand the problem -- as far as I can tell `dotnet` is just plain wrong.
What's going on?
Can it be fixed?
How?

**Update**

This command

```
dotnet publish src\SomeCode.csproj --configuration Release --no-build --no-self-contained --output BuildTest
```

Produces this `runtimeconfig.json` and the app doesn't work.

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.6"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "5.0.6"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

This command

```
dotnet publish src\SomeCode.csproj --configuration Release --no-self-contained --output BuildTest
```

Produces this `runtimeconfig.json` and the app does work.

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

If I overwrite the non-working app's `runtimeconfig.json` with the one from the working app then it starts to work.

Therefore it looks like `dotnet publish` is writing a wrong `runtimeconfig.json`.

Comment: It seems that your code or some library that you are using requires 'hostpolicy.dll'. I would expect that you will NOT find this lib in your '/bin/5.0/debug/' folder.

Comment: ...At the same time this lib probably installed at your PC due to you can run your app locally.
The general idea is that you should somehow add this lib in your project. Maybe there is some nuget that you can install in app that you deploy. 
The other guess is that one libraries you are using uses is a wrapper on some 3rd party library. In this case maybe API allows to change path to 'hostpolicy.dll'. Good luck!

Comment: Did you submit a github issue to DotNet for this bug? It looks like it's an issue with the `--no-build` flag. I hit the exact same problem unfortunately.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue with .net 7 sdk. After removing the `--no-build` flag it was fixed

Comment: I run into the same issue with with .net 6 with VS2022. It is true that removing the --nobuild fix the problem. In my case I run in another issue. I perform publish in a post build event: if I remove --nobuild I get an infinite loop build -> publish -> build -> publish

Comment: If it's a self-contained app, then you should also specify that in the csproj. If it's not a self-contained app, then make sure you have copied over every dependency into your artifact in Azure. Just some thoughts.